# Is non instance object useless in Java?

Tags: java

I really do not know how to precise my question but this is what i mean:

```
Car porsche = new Car(); // im creating instance of the class and i can use it to call methods etc.

Car audi; // is that piece of code useful or useless? what can i do with only this
```

I can not change attributes like in C++ or call methods so what can i do?

Comment: `Car audi;` declares a *variable*. You can later store different objects using that variable, and reference them by the name `audi` in your source code. It's not useless, and it's not an object

Comment: The two lines create variables, one refers to an object, the other holds a null reference. Yes, the latter is useful as you can assign a viable object to it whenever needed. Also, look up "dependency injection" to see how it can be assigned a reference almost "magically"

Comment: The latter is useful if you need to declare it in one spot and create it in another.

Comment: @Powerlord
why not do it in one place?

Comment: @user13630431 Sometimes you can't.  For instance, if this is a class level variable and you expect the user of your class to pass it in via a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It depends the context. But it can be useful *sometime* !

Both lines declare a variable, the first one is directly assigned to an instance of an object. Second one is assigned to `null`

I see one use case right now, but there is more of course.
For example you want to instantiate your object inside another scope :

```java
Car porsche;

try {
    porsche = loadMyCarFromTheGarage(); // this could throw an exception
} catch (GarageEmptyException e) {
    // handle the error, exit, recovery stuff
}

porsche.drive();
... // continue using your car outside the try/catch scope
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
Car porsche = new Car();
```

does a few things. `new Car()` is what creates a new instance of a Car, and returns a reference to that Car.  `Car porsche` declares a variable of a type that can hold a reference to some Car.  And the equals sign `=` initializes the variable (that can hold a reference) with a reference (that resulted from the 'new' expression).

By contrast,

```
Car audi;
```

declares a variable that can hold a reference to a Car. The variable is not currently initialized (if we assume it's a local variable).

```
Car audi = null;
```

explicitly initializes it to refer to no Car at all.

As to whether it's useful.  Well, one major function of a variable is to vary in value.  In the case of Car variable, maybe we want it to potentially hold different car references.

```
Car audi;
if (budget > 160000)
    audi = new Car(AUDI_RS_CONVERTIBLE, NEW);
else {
    haggle_over_used_car_price();
    audi = new Car(AUDI_A3, USED); 
}
```

It is very important in Java to understand the distinction between an object and a reference to an object. Variables hold references to objects; the variable is not the object.

Comment: but I can still do it inline inside if statements like this:

Car audi = new Car(AUDI_RS_CONVERTIBLE, NEW);
else 
Car audi = new Car(AUDI_A3, USED);

Comment: As written in your comment, that code is not legal Java.  If you made the "Car audi = new …" statements into blocks by enclosing each in { … } then it would be legal: but each declaration of Car would be inaccessible outside its block and therefore not useful.